# Active record reputation system - how to check value of current_user's vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rating-system

I'm using the Active Record Reputation System gem and allow users to vote up or down on particular listings.  I'm currently able to check whether a user has voted on a listing by:

```
if current_user && listing.has_evaluation?(:votes, current_user)
```

This tells me whether use user has voted or not, but I need similar logic to tell me whether they voted up or down for that particular listing.  Any thoughts?  Relevant code below:

Within listing model:

```
has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

Within listing controller

```
  def vote
    value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
    listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    listing.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
    redirect_to :back, notice: "Thank you for voting"
  end
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to check whether the user voted up or down for the listing? Figuring out whether they voted on the item is easy, but I can't understand how to retrieve the actual value.

Comment: I ended up making the voting "1" (like) and I destroyed the original evaluation if the user went back and unliked an item (listing.delete_evaluation(:votes, current_user),) within my controller.  Using this logic, you can do the following to find if they've "liked" your item:
@listing.has_evaluation?(:votes, current_user).
Hope that helps.

Comment: I see, so your setup doesnt allow downvoting (-1), just liking and unliking? My trouble is has_evaluation returns true/false, rather than the actual value (+1 or -1). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal in determining the value was so I could show whether the current user had liked a particular page.  The @thing.has_evaluation?(:reputation_name, :source) was not working as it showed the page as "liked" even if a user liked, then disliked.

If anyone runs into this, you can delete an evaluation as the source level by calling the method delete_evaluation, then then a user's previous like/dislike/vote, etc is removed from the system and it's like they never voted.

Primarily helpful if you have a binary voting process